# PhpStorm find all deprecated usages in the project

Tags: php, deprecated, phpstorm

I'm working now on a pretty big PHP-project and I want to upgrade Symfony framework to the next version. Before I do that, I want to be sure that there are no deprecated method usages left in the project.

Is there handy way to find all deprecated method usages in PhpStorm?

Comment: `Code | Run Inspection by Name...` should do the job just fine (as long as new Symfony is already used in a project).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alth +Shift + I</kbd> here on Windows using default keymap) -- search for "deprecated" and choose the most correct one for your needs.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/running-inspections.html#run-one-inspection

This will work as long as new Symfony is already in the project (so that the IDE knows what method/class/constant is now considered deprecated (based on `@deprecated` PHPDoc tags)).

Comment: you can use shortcut key/ hot keys `CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + I`

Comment: On mac: CMD + Option + Shift + I