# PhpStorm ignoring module deprecation

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm currently working on an old project that needs migrating to PHP 5.5 from 5.3

I found out that its possible to have PhpStorm find all deprecated function calls within a project (as per [Find all deprecated usage in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134303/phpstorm-find-all-deprecated-usages-in-the-project)) and to a degree it seems to work really well.

**However** it does not seem to be flagging the now deprecated mysql method calls (of which we have quite a lot). At first I thought this was a PHP version issue but I have checked the settings and PhpStorm is set to use 5.5

The only thing I can seem to find to explain this is that when I ctrl+click on the mysql function calls the phpDoc block for that method does not have an @deprecated attribute.

```
/**
 * (PHP 4, PHP 5)<br/>
 * Close MySQL connection
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php
 * @param resource $link_identifier [optional] 
 * @return bool true on success or false on failure.
 */
function mysql_close ($link_identifier = null) {}
```

Instead this is in the header:

```
// Start of mysql v.1.0
// @deprecated in 5.5 entire extension is deprecated in favour of mysqli
```

Is there a way for me to get PhpStorm to recognise that these functions are deprecated or am I going to have to resort to searching the project?

Note: Mysql functions are pretty simple but what if another modules with less standard modules is disabled?

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134303/phpstorm-find-all-deprecated-usages-in-the-project.
Is it suitable for you?

Comment: @GinoPane - Nope, that's how I'm getting the list of deprecated functions but the mysql functions aren't being listed.

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version?

Comment: @James, here's what I got for this inspection: http://prntscr.com/8u4x5w. As you can see deprecated functions are listed after inspection and even striked out in editor. I'm using PhpStorm 9.0.2.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm using PHPStorm8

Comment: @James Well -- you need PhpStorm v9.0.2 at least -- it works there just fine. P.S. You may try [v10 EAP build](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/10/phpstorm-10-public-preview/) (sort-of beta -- not stable release; can be run alongside; has own 30-days license so can be used even if your current license is expired)

Comment: Confirm working on 9.0.2 version.

Comment: I've updated and that has resolved my issue. Does one of you want to post a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest stable version of PhpStorm v9.0.2 and it definitely has `mysql_` functions marked as deprecated (checked both 9.0.2 and 10 EAP build).

Your version 8 may still have older stubs without `@deprecated` tags for those functions.