# Intellij Idea find all deprecated usages in the project

Tags: intellij-idea, deprecated

I upgrade a language level in IntelliJ Idea in a quite big project and I  would like to find all deprecated method usages left - I look for all the <strike>striketrough</strike> occurrences. 
I have found a similar question for [PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134303/phpstorm-find-all-deprecated-usages-in-the-project) where is suggested an approach:

- <kbd>Code</kbd> → <kbd>Run Inspection by Name...</kbd> → Enter inspection name: `deprecated`

This is not available in the IntelliJ Idea IDE. I work with `2018.3.3` version. Is there a comfortable way to search for all the occurrences?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The action you are looking for is in

- `Code` -> `Analyze Code` -> `Run Inspection by Name` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

The inspection "name" is still `deprecated`, however you will then need to chose a specific inspection in the drop down (e.g. "Deprecated API usage" for Java OR for PHP)

[image]

[image]